# Is there a way to fashion a regex to capture balanced single brackets while not capturing the double brackets and vice versa?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following test sample `[[test case]] with the [second [[test case2]]] and additional [[test [[cases]]]] and the [final test case] or [maybe [not]]`.  I also have the following regexes `\[\[(?:[^\[\]]*|(?R))*\]\]` and `\[(?:[^\[\]]*|(?R))*\]`.

The first regex matches:

1. "[[test case]]", desired
2. "[[test case2]]", a don't care case
3. "[[test [[cases]]]]", desired

The second regex matches:

1. "[[test case]]", not desired as it's a double bracket
2. "[second [[test case2]]]", desired
3. "[[test [[cases]]]]", not desired as it's a double bracket
4. "[final test case]", desired
5. "[maybe [not]]", desired

I've got the regex to capture them in a balanced manner, but I cannot figure out how to make the single bracket regex match only single brackets but still capture the brackets recursively.

What do I need to do to get the second regex to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your designed expressions are just fine, we can just connect them using an alternation,

```
\[\[(?:[^\[\]]*|(?R))*\]\]|(\[(?:[^\[\]]*|(?R))*\])
```

and it would return both desired and undesired matches in separate groups.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RkItiG/1/)

#### Test

```
$re = '/(?:\[\[(?:[^\[\]]*|(?R))*\]\])|(\[(?:[^\[\]]*|(?R))*\])/m';
$str = '[[test case]] with the [second [[test case2]]] and additional [[test [[cases]]]] and the [final test case] or [maybe [not]] ';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Wow.  I can't believe I didn't think of that.  Exactly what I need.